# Variable in enclosed local scope vs variable in global scope - Python

Tags: python, scope, nested, global, local

hi guys I can't figure out why when `find_average()` is called, `total = 20` in the global scope is being used for the `find_total()` function, instead of `total = 10` in the enclosing scope? 
Thanks in advance for any insights and help!

```
total = 20

def find_total(l):
    return total

def find_length(l):
    length = len(l)
    return length

def find_average(l):
    total = 10
    return find_total(l) / find_length(l)


average = find_average(example_list)
```

Comment: What is the Content of example_list?

Comment: total = 10 creates a new variable which is only visible in `find_avarage` not in functions that are called from it

Comment: its supposed to be a list of numbers

Comment: @Jens isn't `find_average` considered the enclosing scope to `find_total`? to my understanding, python looks in the local scope for a variable definition, and then if it does not exist, looks to the enclosing scope for the variable. is this correct or am I getting it wrong? thanks!

Comment: The enclosing scope of `find_total` is the *module*. Scope is defined by *definition* scope, not *calling* scope.

Comment: By the way, unless you are just trying to test variable scope, you may trying to [fix something that is inappropriate for solving your *actual* problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each function has its own scope. It starts at the functions local, inner scope, then goes outwards through enclosing functions until it reaches global (module) scope. This sequence depends on the scope the function is *defined in*. The stack (calling sequence) is *not* used for variable lookup.

In your example, each function only has its inner scope followed by the outer scope. For `find_total`, that's `<module>.find_total.<locals>` and `<module>`. So, whenever `find_total` is run, it will look up `total` in its local scope, failing, and look in the global scope. There, `total == 20`.

The scope inside `find_average` is exclusive to `find_average`. Neither global scope, `find_total` or `find_length` can access it. If you want to pass something from inside `find_average` to `find_total`, you should do so via a parameter.

---

Alternatively, if `find_total` can be defined inside `find_average`. This way, `find_total` resolves names by searching the sequence `<module>.find_average.<locals>.find_total.<locals> -> <module>.find_average.<locals> -> <module>`.

```
total = 20

def find_length(l):
  length = len(l)
  return length

def find_average(l):
  total = 10
  def find_total(l):
    return total
  return find_total(l) / find_length(l)

 average = find_average(example_list)
```

This will make `find_total` *inaccessible* from outside `find_average`!

Comment: ah! so I've misunderstood that the calling sequence(as you mentioned) determines the scopes of the functions. Rather, it is determined by where the functions are defined, e.g., if `find_total` is defined inside `find_average`. Am I correct?